# What is this NOR feedback loop in the AGC Cross Point Generator II?

Tags: oscillator, identification, feedback

This feedback loop looks similar to a [LFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register), however there are no registers present. It looks to be some kind of oscillator.

There seem to be three inputs to this component, `IXP10` (pin 111), `STBE` (pin 237) and `STBF` (pin 239). There is also a tap, `CGMC` (pin 240).

[image: The loop in question]
[image: The loop in context]

Comment: Why not use a simulator and get the operation from that?

Comment: I've done that. On a falling edge on 40240/43 (The three input NOR) a short pulse (High) outputs on CGMC. I leave to others to find out exactly what that means. I don't have the knowledge in how the inputs are generated to find it out. @tofro 's answer below might help.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not an oscillator. The output signal of the circuit is in fact CGMC, which is used to clear the register G after it has been used by multiplication or division operations as an auxiliary register.

STBE and STBF are the strobe signals for **E**rasable and **F**ixed memory.

The whole circuit looks to me like a timing delay generator that is triggered by the memory strobe signals and generates a clear pulse for the G register with a defined length and delay set by the NOR gates' propagation delays.

Source: [This text](https://archive.org/stream/acelectroniclmma00acel_0/acelectroniclmma00acel_0_djvu.txt)